# SpriteNode movement and rotation in Swift 4.1

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite, skspritenode, skaction

I am trying to get my sprite to move and rotate to the location of my touch and follow as I move my finger around the screen.  The movement part is working fine but I can't seem to get it to rotate. My moveAndRotate function is below.

```
func moveAndRotate(spriteNode: SKSpriteNode, toPosition position: CGPoint) {
    let angle = atan2(position.y -  player.position.y, position.x - player.position.x)

    let rotateAction = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: angle - -(CGFloat(Double.pi / 2)), duration: 0.05, shortestUnitArc: true)
    player.run(rotateAction)

    let offsetX = position.x - player.position.x
    let offsetY = position.y - player.position.y
    let normal = simd_normalize(simd_double2(x: Double(offsetX), y: Double(offsetY)))

    velocity = CGVector(dx: CGFloat(normal.x) * movePointsPerSecond, dy: CGFloat(normal.y) * movePointsPerSecond)
}
```

Comment: This is not related, but `angle - -(CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))` can be changed to `angle + CGFloat.pi / 2` to be much more clear.

Comment: Well that may not be related, but it is now rotating, its lagging some but an improvement over what I had.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: Your project must just be buggy. It happens to Xcode very often. The code I talked about is equivalent in output. If you don't want SpriteKit to be laggy, run your project on a real device.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but its laggy on my iPhone XS Max as well.  Anyway thanks for your input.

Comment: If you are calling `moveAndRotate` from `touchesMoved`, you are likely calling the method again before the last action has completed. You can avoid this by running the action with a key and if the action already exist (when `moveAndRotate` is called), remove it before create/running a new action.

Comment: You are stacking your actions, you need to remove the previous rotation before you add a new one

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, I had the duration set to 0.5 on my rotateAction.  that would account for the lag.  duh!

Answer (score 0):

The duration was set to o.5 on the rotateAction, change it to 0 and it works fine.